# Server not Recognising Cookie From Android Phone

Tags: android, drupal, cookies

I am trying to connect to a drupal server. I have been able to do this in the past but the drupal developers now require me to add another cookie. The server does not register the cookie that I am trying to send below. Can anybody see why?

```
public static void maybeCreateHttpClient() {
    if (mHttpClient == null) {
        mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        final HttpParams params = mHttpClient.getParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params,
            REGISTRATION_TIMEOUT);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, REGISTRATION_TIMEOUT);
        ConnManagerParams.setTimeout(params, REGISTRATION_TIMEOUT);



        BasicCookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
        ClientCookie cookie = new BasicClientCookie("aml", key);

        cookieStore.addCookie(cookie);

        localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);


    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that, I didn't need to use cookie, cookstore or httpcontent. As far as I can understand these are mainly used to managed cookies coming from the server.

I managed to solve my problem by setting a header like so

```
    String key = "whatever";

    post.addHeader("Cookie", "aml=" + key);
```

This can be used on httppost, httpget or httput.

That took me a few days for such a simple solution. I hope it helps somebody else out

Comment: which would make sense since cookies _are_ usually coming from the server, aren't they?

Comment: well yes the session id and session name are but the aml that I am sending isn't. The problem was that the server wouldn't recognize separate cookies when android was handling them. So I need to send them in a specific way. With a comma seperating them rather than a semi colon.

Answer (score -1):

Oh, well if you're looking for why the cookies weren't added, you weren't getting or adding the cookie store from the http client.  You should get the cookie store from the client, add your cookies, and then execute your request.

Comment: But in that case it would send the cookies that it had already got from the server. Thats the whole problem.